# Folder full of files showing "This folder is empty" message

Tags: windows-explorer

I've got a folder full of podcasts but I can't see them. When I look them up on Everything then right click any search result and "open path" it takes me to that exact folder but when I just straight navigate to that folder in File Explorer, it simply shows nothing, although when I actually right click on the page with the "This folder is empty" message and see the properties, it actually tells me correctly that the folder has 209 files and 9.02GB. What is happening here? I'm on Windows 8 Pro x64

Comment: What do you see when you open a command window, navigate to the directory with `cd`, and do `dir /A`?

Comment: It shows all the files that are in the folder normally :-|

Comment: File Explorer is flaky, especially with "media" files.  Try doing RMB in the folder, selecting "Customize this folder", and changing it to "All items".  (At least that's the Vista sequence.)